# How to select First Value In Group By Order by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can select first value of a column order by another column when I'm in a group by ?

My Data:

```
ID       UserId        HashText          Text          Date
-------------------------------------------------------
1        1000          123               Hi            2018-10-10
2        2000          124               Hello         2018-10-11
3        3000          123               Hi            2018-10-12
4        4000          123               Hi            2018-10-13
```

My Result:

```
UserId        HashText      count
-------------------------------------------------------
1000          123           3
2000          124           1
```

One Note: I cant use `min(UserId)` - it's not always `sort` by `UserId`

Comment: Tables does not have fields, they have columns and rows, please edit your question show us what did you try, the actual data and expected result as _formatted text_ not _images_ please.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support `first_value()` as an aggregation function.  But, you can use a trick if you have an aversion to subqueries:

```
select distinct first_value(userId) over (partition by hashtext order by id) as userId,
       hashtext
       count(*) over (partition by hashtext) as cnt
from mydata;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` with `ties` clause :

```
select top (1) with ties UserId, HashText, cnt
from table t cross apply
     ( select count(*) as cnt
       from table t1 
       where t1.HashText = t.HashText 
     ) t1
order by row_number() over (partition by HashText order by id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This displays the output.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(userid) >= 1 THEN MIN(userid) ELSE NULL END UserId, b.hashtext, b.count FROM Table t
JOIN (SELECT hashtext, COUNT(userid) COUNT FROM Table t GROUP BY hashtext) b 
ON t.hashtext=b.hashtext 
GROUP BY b.count, b.hashtext
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HashText ORDER BY (UserId) ASC)`

**Query**

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(ID int,UserId int, HashText  int, Text varchar(5), Datevalue Date)
INSERT INTO #temp(ID,UserId,HashText,Text,Datevalue)
select 1, 1000,123,'Hi'    ,       '2018-10-10' union
select 2, 2000,124,'Hello',        '2018-10-11' union
select 3, 3000,123,'Hi' ,          '2018-10-12' union
select 4, 4000,123,'Hi',           '2018-10-13' 

Select * from #temp 

;with CTE as (
Select UserId,HashText,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HashText ORDER BY (UserId) ASC) sort
FRom #temp
),getCount as 
(SELECT HashText, COUNT(userid) [Count] 
FROM #temp t GROUP BY hashtext)
SElect UserId, C.HashText, [Count] 
FROM CTE C
JOIN getCount T ON
T.HashText = C.HashText
WHERE sort = 1
```

**Output:**

[image]